# how to use implicit in c#

Tags: c#, class, implicit

I have two classes as below:

```
class Bear : IPersonality
    {
        ...
    }

class Friend<T> where T : IPersonality
    {
        T friend;

        public Friend(T animal)
        {
            friend = animal;
        }

        ...

        public static implicit operator Friend<T>(Bear v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

How can I use an implicit operator to be able to create an instance of Friend class like this ?

```
Friend<Bear> bear = new Bear("Pooh", 5);
```

Comment: You are probably looking for `public static implicit operator Friend<T>(T animal) =>
        animal == null ? null : new Friend<T>(animal);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use generics `T` for any animal, keep doing it in `implicit`:

```
 class Friend<T> where T : IPersonality {
   ... 

   public static implicit operator Friend<T>(T animal) => 
     animal == null ? null : new Friend<T>(animal);
 }
```

If only `Bear` can be an implicit friend (but not, say, `Rabbit`), move the code into `Bear`:

```
class Bear : IPersonality {
  ... 

  public static implicit operator Friend<Bear>(Bear bear) =>
    bear == null ? null : new Friend<Bear>(bear);
}
```

Comment: it's kind of a strange example to work with.  I like to think of [Nullable<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-5.0) as a standard use case.  I conceptualized on an `Audit<T>` type in similar fashion.  But this concept of `Friend<T>` seems less of a descriptor and more relational.